# Breadcrumb Not Linking to the Correct Custom Post Type Index Page(s)

Tags: custom-post-types, breadcrumb

I wrote this code for 2 **custom post types** to link back to their respective index
pages from the single post view. It works. However the "Portfolio" and "Artwork" will have **multiple** pages and I am unclear on what to append to this code to recognize those additional pages as they are created by the user. The page name progression is (for example) `portfolio/page/2/`, `portfolio/page/3/` etc, but all **single post** breadcrumbs are linking back to the **first** custom post type index page. Any help is so appreciated but please be concise because my coding skills and Wordpress knowledge are *intermediate* at best.

```
global $post;  
  $type = get_post_type($post->ID);  
  if($type == 'portfolio'){  
echo '<a href="' . 'http://www.foo.com/portfolio'  . '">' . 'Portfolio' .  '</a>' . $markup;
  } else if($type == 'artwork'){
echo '<a href="' . 'http://www.foo.com/artwork'  . '">' . 'Artwork' .  '</a>' . $markup;
}}
```

Comment: What do you want breadcrumb to link to? Page of the archive the post is currently on? That's a little unorthodox, I don't think I've seen (or would have expected) breadcrumb link working like that.

Comment: Yes, what I am trying to do may be a little unconventional but it works and it's creative, no? I am trying to add to this code _additional_ breadcrumb links to the correct index page of /page/2/, page/3/, I thought I made myself clear on that. My apologies if not, and thanks for looking into it. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hm. This is interesting since WP is made for resolving "which posts are on page X", but doesn't have anything (that I can think of) for "on which page post Y is".

Comment: Rather that "unrealistic" I would put it like "prone to be extremely fragile" solution and I am hesitant to just come up with something quick and hardcoded that would be non-reusable.

Comment: It's a breadcrumb so I am not too concerned about fragility. Is there no code that will recognize the additional index pages? Will anyone lend their insight?